# Dynamics CRM - Copy Workflow for a different entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm relatively new to Microsoft Dynamics CRM (which has changed to Microsoft Dynamics 365).

I currently have an issue where I need to redo some of the processes of an existing workflow for an existing entity, to another entity. This task in itself is very time consuming and rather tedious.

I thought that it may be possible to duplicate the workflow and update the entity, but that does not seem possible, but only for the same entity - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/altavistatechnology/posts/duplicating-workflow-in-dynamics-crm

Is there a way for me to either reuse, or somehow quicken the process of doing these tasks? The process is to have multiple check conditions for numerous values and update a field in the form, if those conditions have been met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that I could have multiple values within the field (as I kept creating a new check condition for each individual value, but the field can take multiple values separated by a ; )

So this had helped quicken the process (as I did create multiple check conditions which I did find silly....)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this Workflow template concept is only option to copy/save-as/clone the WF logic into a new WF, and this supports only within the same entity.

There may be unsupported approaches to extract the solution xml/xaml & have some adventurous efforts for overcome this. But that's not recommended & you may not see lot of documentation for that path.

That's the benefit of using Custom workflow activity, custom action or Plugin to do reusable code blocks, but this UI WF copy across entities is not a viable option by OOB.

Depending upon the logic, you can try child workflow concept which can be reused. But not sure if that works on your case without seeing the logic implemented.

Comment: I take it a custom workflow would require custom code to be implemented as per this tutorial below? Also, is there another quicker way to add conditions aside from manual input? No automated way or bulk process? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg309745(v=crm.8) Thanks for your help @Arun

Comment: @Javz its very rare for an entity to have same attributes as another entity and logics like this.. so I could not think of any way to do this.. I'm a developer, so my brain think always a code solution.. low code/no code is at minimal.. also MS Flow (Power Automate) may solve this in future

Comment: So ultimately, if I want to achieve what I want I would have to go for custom code. But putting the same workflow aside, what about for adding multiple conditions for a workflow? E.g. Entity X Field Y Equals to A, and repeat until Z, is there a better of doing those aside from doing it manually?

Comment: I think this is also entity dependent? -https://www.inogic.com/blog/2009/02/design-a-workflow-for-performing-repetitive-tasks/ As in this example it requires an entity of given type to work. Thanks for your help @Arun!